# Uploading large files causing error

Tags: php, file-upload, fine-uploader

So here is my problem. I was using fineuploader to add drag and drop support to my form. I used PHP to do all the processing. When I was running on my local WAMP server everything worked fine. (Including files 100MB+)  When I switched over to my production server the error started occurring.

Files will still upload just fine to a point. Testing with a 50MB file worked flawlessly. When trying to upload a 100MB file, it creates an error.

Output from console for small file:

```
[Fine Uploader 5.5.0] xhr - server response received for 0
jquery.fine-uploader.js:251 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] responseText = {"success":true,"uuid":"2f5b7015-a573-4159-b225-8b2e006aa83b","uploadName":"PTO Request Form.pdf"}
jquery.fine-uploader.js:251 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Received response status 200 with body: {"success":true,"uuid":"2f5b7015-a573-4159-b225-8b2e006aa83b","uploadName":"PTO Request Form.pdf"}
jquery.fine-uploader.js:251 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Simple upload request succeeded for 0
```

Output from a large file:

```
[Fine Uploader 5.5.0] xhr - server response received for 1
jquery.fine-uploader.js:251 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] responseText = {"error":"here: File name empty.","uploadName":null}
jquery.fine-uploader.js:251 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Received response status 200 with body: {"error":"File name empty.","uploadName":null}
jquery.fine-uploader.js:251 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Simple upload request failed for 1
```

I've tried increasing/removing the PHP time limits with:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('max_input_time', 0);
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '500M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '500M');
set_time_limit(0);
```

but it produced the same result. I've tried catching the post data myself and passing it into the upload function, but still results in the same outcome.

Please, if anyone has any insight, pass it my way.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: copied local ini_set code leaving out the file size increases.

Comment: http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/03-setting_up_server.html - check the docs step 2

Comment: `post_max_size` or maybe `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: show the php code handling the upload.

Comment: Edit: I think you guys are right, though. After I looked further into it my php installation is not letting me override the size limit settings. I tested a file right under the current limit (60M) and it uploaded fine. That has to be the issue. I'll get my server admin to change it tomorrow and report back.

Comment: If you weren't able to restart apache without your admin, that's probably the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After further testing and others hinting in the direction. The solution was to increase the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in the php.ini. Setting them with ini_set does not work as the settings are required prior to the page being processed.

I don't have direct access so I used htaccess to accomplish the same thing.

.htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size 500M
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: This is fine for old browser uploads, but for modern browsers you should be using the [file chunking feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/chunking.html) instead.

Comment: You can't use ini_set because the files have already been uploaded/rejected before PHP actually starts to execute; that's why you have to change these settings in your php.ini or htaccess

Comment: Mark, I didn't realize that at first yesterday which led me through a grueling couple hours of "what the hell moments". @RayNicholus I took your advice and switched to enable the chunking feature. Thanks to both of you.